# Get HTML title with QTWebkit

Tags: qt4, qtwebkit

I'm using this code:

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView(this);   
QUrl *app_path = new QUrl(path);

view->load(*app_path);
view->show();

QWebFrame *frame = view->page()->mainFrame();
QWebElement dom_title = frame->findFirstElement("title");
QString title = dom_title.evaluateJavaScript("this.text").toString();
out << title << endl;
```

However `title` is empty. What am I missing? Checked some examples but nothing seems wrong.

Comment: You want to make sure that the page is completely loaded. Do some testing with frame->setContent("<html><head><title>Foo</title></head><body>test</body><html>") and check the result.

Comment: @AriyaHidayat That was the problem. Post this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the page finished loading. Otherwise, the DOM is not ready yet and thus it will give an undefined behavior.